# Why is this error showing up when I am trying to update database from MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm getting this error I can't quite figure out.

```
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^
TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function
```

I'm making this command line app for a homework for my coding bootcamp. The bulk of the code is working up until I get until the last else statement. That is where the error is being thrown. I'm not really understanding the error. I have to make it so the quantity is being updated in the MySQL database.

```
    inquirer
        .prompt([
            {
                name: "choice",
                type: "input",
                message: "What is the ID# of the product you would like to purchace?",
            }, {
                name: "qtySelection",
                message: "How many units of would you like?",
                type: "input"
            }
        ]).then(function (result) {

            var query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE item_id = ?";
            connection.query(query, result.choice, function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (!res.length) {
                    console.log("\r\n");
                    console.log("Sorry item not in inventory, please try again.");
                    setTimeout(userPurchase, 1000);
                } else {
                    if (result.qtySelection > res[0].stock_quantity) {
                        console.log("\r\n");
                        console.log("Sorry we do not enough have enough in stock! PLeas try again!");
                        setTimeout(userPurchase, 1000);
                    } else {

                        var newQty = parseInt(res[0].stock_quantity) - parseInt(result.qtySelection)
                        connection.query("UPDATE products SET stock_quantity = ? WHERE item_id = ?", newQty, result.choice, function (err, result) {
                            // if (err) throw err;
                            console.log("Thank you for purchasing " + result.qtySelection + "of " + result.choice + ". Your total is $" + parseInt(result.qtySelection) * parseInt(res[0].price))

                        })
                    }
                    connection.end();
                }
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: The only line like that in the code is commented out, so it can't cause this error.

Comment: oh yea, I commented that out and forgot to put it back in to see if that was the problem.

Comment: Try using `console.log(err)` instead of `throw err`.